# String case reverse function in C

Tags: c, strings

This reverses the case of a character in a string (a string being an array of characters). How does it look? Anything I can improve on? Besides documentation, in particular, any thoughts on the type casting found in `str_case_rev`?

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fprintf
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc
#include <string.h> // strlen
#include <ctype.h>  // toupper, tolower

/*
 * a string is an array of characters, in C, all arrays
 * are always passed never passed value, always a pointer to
 * the variable
 * This is why the caller does not need to call the function like:
 * camel_case_rev(src, &dest, len)
 *
 * Since here the array of characters ("a string") is already being
 * passed as a pointer value
 */
void str_case_rev(const char *src, char *dest, size_t len)
{
        size_t i = 0;

        for(; i < len; i++)
        {
                if(src[i] <= 'Z' && src[i] >= 'A')
                {
                        *(dest + i) = (char)tolower((int)src[i]);
                }
                else if(src[i] <= 'z' && src[i] >= 'a')
                {
                        *(dest + i) = (char)toupper((int)src[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                        *(dest + i) = src[i];
                }
        }

        i++;
        *(dest + i) = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if(argc < 2)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        char *dest = NULL;

        size_t len = strlen(argv[1]);

        dest = malloc(len + 1);

        if(NULL == dest)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory error\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        str_case_rev(argv[1], dest, len);

        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", dest);

        free(dest);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The case determination code (`src[i] <= 'Z' && src[i] >= 'A'`) doesn't look right (think about locales). `isupper` and `islower` are specifically designed to deal with that. Besides, you are already using `toupper` and `tolower`.

Answer (score 3):

I would call a function to convert uppercase to lowercase and vice versa something like `str_case_toggle()`.

I am puzzled by the `len` parameter in the function signature. Usually, C strings are null-terminated. Since this function only makes sense on text strings and not binary data, I think that it makes more sense to look for the null terminator in `src` than to state the length explicitly.

On the other hand, sometimes functions accept a `bufsize` parameter, which has subtly different semantics. A `bufsize` indicates the size of the destination buffer and helps to prevent buffer overflows. However, in that case, I would still expect the the loop to stop if it encounters a NUL byte in `src` first, so as not to try to read possibly invalid memory.

Comment: Agree with your `bufsize` ideas.  Note: In C, strings always, by definition, have a null character termination, else that `char` array is not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than have a big conversion statement I would just do:

```
 static const char convert[] = {
                          0, 1 ,2 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
                          ....
                          /* The character code for 'A' 65 replace with 'a' 97 */

                          62, 63, 64, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
                          ....
                          /* The character code for 'a' 97 replace with 65 'A' */
                          94, 95, 96, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 

                          ....
                          248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255};

 void str_case_rev(const unsigned char *src, char *dest, size_t len)
 {
     for(; i < len; i++)
     {
         dest[i] = convert[src[i]];
     }
     dest[len] = '\0';
 }
```

Then all you have to do is define the conversion in a single array.
Since a char is only 8 bits you only need to define an array of 255 characters (just make sure you use unsigned char).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the array of 255 characters. Admittedly, I don't have a lot of experience with bit shifting.

Comment: `convert[src[len]];` will not work as desired should `char` be signed. Suggest `convert[(unsigned char) src[len]];`

Comment: @chux: Fixed first. Second does not apply as src is already unsigned char.

Comment: @Loki Astari Oops - did not notice you changed the function signature - hmmmm: not so keen on that.  IAC, we agree the index to `convert[]` should be unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

1. `i++;` after the loop is functionally wrong. Delete it.

   ```
   // i++;
   *(dest + i) = '\0';
   ```
2. `size_t len` is a problem.  If it represents the result of `strlen(src)`, then it is not needed as `str_case_rev()` can calculate that.  If `len` represents the `size` of `src`, then writing the `'\0'` is occurring outside the size of `src` even with the above fix.
3. If code uses `tolower()`, using `isupper()` makes more sense than `if(src[i] <= 'Z' && src[i] >= 'A')`.
4. Consider returning something useful rather than `void str_case_rev()`.  Suggest returning `dest` or a flag indicating *some* toggling occurred.

   ```
   char *str_case_rev(const char *src, char *dest, size_t len) {
      ...
      return dest;
   }
   ```
5. Consider re-ordering to match `str...()` functions like `char *strcpy(char * dest,
   const char *src);`

   ```
   char *str_case_rev(char *dest, const char *src, size_t len) {
      ...
      return dest;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The lookup table method would probably be faster but otherwise the logic of the code is just fine.

However, although I realize you're just practicing your skills, it should be noted that this routine would not be suitable for processing real text. Real text routines need to handle non-ascii text. Today that means either UTF-8 on non-Windows systems or UTF-16LE on Windows systems. Specifically, on non-Windows systems you would need to do mbrtowc and then towupper or towlower and then wcstombs within each iteration of your loop. On Windows systems the logic would be the same but the exact functions would be different. Fortunately this sort of thing (toggling the case of a string) is quite rare. Something like comparing two non-ascii strings in a caseless way is a more realistic example but fortunately still rare.